How to set Dialog Fragmenrt to fullscreen (EdgeToEdge)
Developing for Android 13, I can make the activity to fullscreen by using  EdgeToEdge.enable((ComponentActivity) this); . But for a dialog no matter how I tried, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/55243088/1099884 .The dialog still be shown from "under the top bar" not actual fullscreen.
How can I enable edge-to-edge for a dialog?

OK.By investigating EdgeToEdge implementation. It can be enabled on dialogs for Android 11.
Custom dialog theme is necessary.
<style name="FullScreenDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
        <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>

Then on DialogFragment
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.FullScreenDialogTheme);
}

inflate the dialog layout on onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) , not sure on onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) works or not.
And then the minimum for adjust the window behaviour (Android 11 above)
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        if (dialog != null) {
            //NOT ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, need exact the width/height
            int width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.screen_width);
            int height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.screen_height);
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
            Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
            if(window != null){
                WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
                    window.getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_ALWAYS;
                    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    window.setNavigationBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    window.setStatusBarContrastEnforced(false);
                    window.setNavigationBarContrastEnforced(false);
                    WindowInsetsControllerCompat controller = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.getDecorView());
                    controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
                    controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars());
                    controller.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

